# Android : android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I'm trying to create an adapter for my fragments but I get this :

Error:(19, 72) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

This is a part of my main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // == Setting up the ViewPager ==

    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),this);    <--- Error is on this line
```

And this is a part of my customAdapter class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

protected Context mContext;

public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` should extend [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) and you should use [`getSupportFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) method instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your code, not `getFragmentManager()`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) why

Answer (score 1):

Your **FragmentPagerAdapter** is of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`
either change it to `android.app.FragmentPageAdapter`

or change this

```
 mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),this);
```

to

```
mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
```

will solve your problem Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

please use getSupportFragmentManager(); to resolve your problems